# LWCWebpackPlugin + Storybook Custom Webpack Config

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working to integrate [LWCWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/davidturissini/lwc-webpack-plugin) into [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) for prototyping components.

This has been done using a [one-off POC project](https://github.com/reiniergs/lwc-storybooks-poc), which works by defining it's own `webpack.config.js` [file](https://github.com/reiniergs/lwc-storybooks-poc/blob/master/.storybook/webpack.config.js):

```
 config.plugins.push(
    new LWCWebpackPlugin({
        namespace: {
            // LWC Namespace with path
            lightning: path.resolve('./src/lightning'),
            c: path.resolve('./src/c'),
        },
        modules: [
            "@salesforce-ux/design-system"
        ]
    })
);
```

However, I would like to move this same configuration to the `app/x-framework-config.ts` file per the [preset-framework-support structure.](https://github.com/jordanbaucke/storybook-framework-boilerplate/blob/lwc-2/app/lwc/src/server/lwc-preset-framework.ts)

```
plugins: [
  new LWCWebpackPlugin({
      namespace: {
          // LWC Namespace with path
          c: path.resolve('./c'),
      },
      modules: [
          "@salesforce-ux/design-system"
      ]
  })
],
```

However, after I follow the same structure, in the skeleton, I do not see the plugin being detected in the when I review the webpack-config (`cd examples/lwc-kitchen-sink && yarn storybook --debug-webpack`)

I get an error (assuming babel is not properly configured to process the "lwc decorators", as it errors on `@api`